# Concatenating char[] with another char[]

Tags: c, char, arduino-ide, progmem

I'm finishing up an Sketch with the Arduino IDE and to be able to run it on UNO, I have to work with C `char[]`. Which has not been easy for me and I already asked something regarding this a short while ago.

I need to create a longer `char[]` by concatenating smaller parts. So far I've been able to do it by something like this:

```
//Declarations 

    #define TARGET_IP "184.106.153.149"

//Methods

    void randomMethod(){

     strcpy(foo, "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"");
     strcat(foo, TARGET_IP);
     strcat(foo, "\",80\r\n");
     Serial.println(foo);

    }
```

However in my code I have a lot of static string which eat up most of the 2K RAM memory, so I would like to make use of the PROGMEM 
So I tried the following:

```
//Declarations

#define TARGET_IP "184.106.153.149"

static const char targetIp[] PROGMEM = TARGET_IP;


//Methods

void randomMethod(){

         strcpy(foo, "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"");
         strcat(foo, targetIp);
         strcat(foo, "\",80\r\n");
         Serial.println(foo);

        }
```

When printing on the serial monitor the first snippet works just fine whereas the second does not.

I've been trying to google it, but to no avail.

Any further education from you guys and gals will be most appreciate it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `foo` defined?

Comment: [First search engine hit for PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/) explains that you have to use special functions to access progmem memory. You can't just treat them like regular variables.

Comment: On the top of the Sketch, with all the other definitions. It is well defined, as char foo[400];

Comment: @RaymondChen I swear to you I had this page on a tab on my browser... I'm going to see to it

Comment: Rather than concatenate 3 strings, perhaps print with `Serial.` 3 times?

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to write your own PROGMEM versions of strcpy, strcat, etc. (These are very simple functions, so it shouldn't be difficult). Or try to figure out how to accomplish your goal with less memory.